# How can be the state-space representation rewritten into differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

I know generally, we transform differential equations into the space-state representation by substituting the derivatives with the states.

However, I would need the opposite - given the state space representation to arrive at the differential equation format (in order to design a PID controller).

$$
\dot x_{1}=-x_{1}+x_{2}
$$
$$
\dot x_{2}=-x_{1}+u
$$

$$
A\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}x \quad
B\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix}u
$$

As one differential equation has multiple ways to be represented in state-space I am unsure how this works in the opposite way.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you looking for how to convert the system of differential equations into a single higher order equation?  Does this help: [Transform the system into a single fourth-order ODE in either x or y](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234778/transform-the-system-into-a-single-fourth-order-ode-in-either-x-or-y)

Comment: What is exactly what you call _state-space representation_?

Answer (score 3):

For this specific example,
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\dot{x}_1 &= -x_1 + x_2 \\
\dot{x}_2 &= -x_1 + u
\end{split} \implies
\begin{split}
\ddot{x}_1 &= -\dot{x}_1 + \dot{x}_2 \\
\dot{x}_2 &= \underline{-x_1 + u}
\end{split} \implies
\ddot{x}_1 = -\dot{x}_1 + \underline{u - x_1} \implies \ddot{x}_1 + \dot{x}_1 + x_1 = u
\end{align}
where we substituted $\dot{x}_2$ (the underlined equation) into $\ddot{x}_1$. In general, if you have a single input single output system of the form,
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\dot{x} &= Ax + B u \\
y &= Cx + Du
\end{split}
\end{align}
You can compute the transfer function $G(s) = C(sI - A)^{-1}B + D$. Let $G(s) = \frac{P(s)}{Q(s)}$ where $P(s)$ is a polynomial of $s$ in the numerator and $Q(s)$ is a polynomial of $s$ in the denominator of $G(s)$. Then from $Y(s) = G(s)U(s) = \frac{P(s)}{Q(s)}U(s)$ we can get $Q(s)Y(s) = P(s)U(s)$ and by taking the inverse Laplace transform we can obtain the differential equation, i.e., $\mathcal{L}^{-1}(Q(s)Y(s)) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}(P(s)U(s))$. For your example,
\begin{align}
A = \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \quad B = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} \quad C = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \quad D = 0
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
C(sI - A)^{-1}B + D = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}s+1 & -1 \\ 1 & s\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{s^2+s+1}
\end{align}
and from the transfer function we can obtain,
\begin{align}
Y(s) = \frac{1}{s^2+s+1} U(s) \implies (s^2+s+1)Y(s) = U(s) \overset{\mathcal{L}^{-1}}{\implies} \ddot{y} + \dot{y} + y = u
\end{align}
Since $y=x_1$ we can write this as $\ddot{x}_1 + \dot{x}_1 + x_1 = u$ (same as above).